# How can I animate the text that appears on my Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Carousel on my website with three elements  like this:

```
            <a><img data-src="img" alt="Third slide" src="img">
        </a>
         <div class="carousel-caption">             
        <h2>  
  <ul id="columncarro4" type="circle" style="">
          <li>text1</li><br>
          <li>text</li><br>
          <li>text</li>

          </ul>

         </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And some Javascript to move the position of the text the way I want:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#columncarro4').animate({
                           'margin-left':'-3%'
                },500).animate({

                           'margin-left':'-255px'
                },'slow');
      });
```

I want the animation of the second slide to begin when the second carousel slide appears.

I have three animations but they start since the start of the webpage and they don't appear with the slide.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: My carousel changes the slide every 5 seconds, I need that the animation begins when the carousel changes

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#columncarro4').animate({...
```

That code will start the animate function on document ready - page fully loaded. You have to wrap it with another event that - when do you want it to start exactly, after what happened? For example if you want the animation to start after a click on your Carousel you should do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#columncarro4').click(function(){
            $('#columncarro4').animate({
                       'margin-left':'-3%'
            },500).animate({

                       'margin-left':'-255px'
            },'slow');
        });
  });
```

Comment: That´s right thanks, but the carousel changes every five seconds So i need an animation that begins when the carousel change.

Answer (score 0):

Use SetInterval()

### Edit:

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var interval;
    function animate() {
        $('#columncarro4').animate({'margin-left':'-3%'}, 500)
        .animate({'margin-left':'-255px'}, 'slow');
    }
    function start() {
        interval = setInterval(animate, 5000);
    }
    $('#columncarro4').click( function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        animate();
        start();
    });
    start();
});
```

Or if you have a event that is fired when the carusel changes you can bind to that.

Comment: thanks but I have the problem that I have indicators so the user can also change the slide manually

Comment: use both functions, play the animation every 5 seconds and also on user click, might also disable setInterval if needed for some time  by wrapping the function inside it in an if block that checks a control variable

Comment: thank you im trying this code but i dont know why is not working but it seems to be well done. when is the start call made?

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez What is your problem? The start code is made when document.ready() fires.

Comment: `$('#columncarro4').clicked(`  should be `$('#columncarro4').click(`